Get Parent Info win32_PNPEntity
I wrote this simple code:
static void Main()
{
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM win32_PNPEntity WHERE PnPClass='Camera'"))
    {
        foreach (var device in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"DeviceID => {device["DeviceID"]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"PNPDeviceID => {device["PNPDeviceID"]}");
        }
    }
}

I want to get the Parent property but it doesn't seem to exist.
If I go to Device Manager -> Camera -> My Camera -> Property -> Details I see that property (see image). How can I get it back?


My experience with WMI (both with PowerShell and C#) generally involves Trial and error and cussing. I'm not near a machine right now. Have you tried to get the collection? It looks like something like this might help to get that list foreach (PropertyData property in device.Properties) {//etc. From there you can probably figure it out

@Flydog57 Nope, I printed all the properties and its value but the Parent info not found

The Parent property object is part of the Entity's Properties. You have to invoke the GetDeviceProperties() method to get the instances. It's probably simpler if you use Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure (v. 3.0 - no COM objects, the library already converts them to .NET types) instead of System.Management (but you can get there anyway)

is you question or camera class only or is it more general?
